# Permission denied when I copy letsencrypt folder using scp

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, winscp

I want to copy letsencrypt folder from my remote ec2 machine to my local folder.

So I run this command:

```
scp -i key.pem -r ubuntu@ec2-3-188-92-58.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/etc/letsencrypt my-letsencrypt
```

Some files are copied but other failed with this error `Permission denied`:

```
scp: /etc/letsencrypt/archive: Permission denied
scp: /etc/letsencrypt/keys: Permission denied
```

I want to avoid to change ec2 files permissions.

What can I do to copy this folder to my local filesystem?

Comment: That question is an edge case. It little bit about scripting -- Imo, it's off-topic too -- But your question is plain user problem with permissions - You would get the same problem even if you used a GUI SCP client.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming/code questions. Not general Linux usage. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2):

You are logging in with the account `ubuntu` on the server, but that account doesn't have the correct permission to read (and therefore) copy all the files. Most likely some of the files are owned by `root` and are not readable by others.
You can check the permission yourself with `ls -l /etc/letsencrypt`.

To copy the files anyway, here's two options:

## 1. Make a readable copy

on the remote server (logged in via SSH), you can make a copy of the folder, and change the permissions of the files:

```
sudo cp -r /etc/letsencrypt ~/letsencrypt-copy
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu ~/letsencrypt-copy
```

Now you can copy the files from there:

```
scp -i key.pem -r ubuntu@ec2-3-188-92-58.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:letsencrypt-copy my-letsencrypt
```

## 2. copy from root

If you have ssh access on the root account, then just copy using that account:

```
scp -r root@ec2-3-188-92-58.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:letsencrypt-copy my-letsencrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need public read permission
 - First `SSH` to your remote server ubuntu@ec2-3-188-92-58.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

- `sudo su -`  (make sure you are a root user)
- `chmod -R 0744 /etc/letsencrypt`

now try to download again with SCP again
after download put back permissions to 0700

- `chmod -R 0700 /etc/letsencrypt`

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions for archive & keys. It should be 400. Just change to 600. After the change, try copying again.

```
chmod -R 600 ./archive ./keys
```

Comment: I run `bash` and `chmod -R 600 key.pem` Still I got `Permission denied`.